# What is the best practice to implement a logout in NESTJS controller and invalidate the jwt token?

Tags: typescript, api, jwt, nestjs, logout

I am planning to implement a logout functionality in a nestjs controller, searching around, I could not find any source that was useful. I have to call the logout function and invalidate the jwt then provide a response to the FE.
Any help, or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

A JWT is self-contained and is not designed to be invalidated, it will be valid until it expires.

If you want to block access to backend API's when a user logs out you may consider the following strategies:

1. Use opaque [OAuth access tokens](https://oauth.net/2/access-tokens/) for securing API's instead of JWT's (opaqe access tokens can normally be [revoked on the Authorization Server](https://oauth.net/2/token-revocation/) which issued them).
2. Use a traditional session when for all the communications between your backend and your frontend. (see also [NestJS sessions](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/session)).
3. Maintain an blacklist of revoked JWT tokens (or a whitelist of valid tokens) in your backend.

While you could use a JWT for securing access to a backend API (e.g. a REST API) it is considered a [bad practice to use a JWT for maintaining a session](http://cryto.net/%7Ejoepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/). If you want to maintain a session between backend and frontend, you should use a traditional session mechanism.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the answer. I think point 3 is what I need to implement. Could you elaborate more on that, or provide some more details please.

Comment: I would use a simple cache to store the JWT with a key to identify each token and the token expiration timestamp to automatically remove expired entries (once the token is expired you no longer need to black list it).

Comment: The key could be the token itself, the [JTI](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519#section-4.1.7) claim or the token signature

The expiration is found in the [exp](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519#section-4.1.4) claim.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the answer. Could you please point some resources regarding the caching to store the jwt?. I read that redis is an option here. Thanks

Comment: Hi @AhmedJ. any update about this? I'm seeking a solution but still no appropriate one suite my need, which is the same as your question